# How to apply "custom animations" on "List Picker" and "Date Picker" in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: xaml, animation, windows-phone-8, datepicker, listpicker

How to apply custom "Open/Close" animations on "List Picker" and "Date Picker" in Windows Phone 8?

Answer (score 0):

The `ListPicker` and `DatePicker` are part of the toolkit. You can get the code from http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest.

You can then modify a copy of the source, in your solution, and change the transitions that are used to get to and from the pages.